# TODO with Reminder management

Tags: workflow, reminders

AFAIK there are numerous softwares for TODO lists (quite simple) and CRM (quite complex)

What I am looking for is more like a TODO list but with a feature to have a reminder tracker because many TODOs are delegated.

A data model which captures the nature of the reminder i.e. how many iterations are there, and their due dates, would help a lot to plan activities like "whom I need to remind today".

Comment: Hi. Please also list the TODO systems you have already looked at that don't meet your requirements. Also, what platform do you want to run it on?

Comment: There are a multitude of todo list questions on here. Did you do any research first? What did you find & why wasn't it suitable?

Comment: Further, what OS should it run on? What about pricing? Apart of a reminder tracker, what features do you need?